# Equivalence of graph properties: minimum degree and cycle existence

Tags: graph-theory

I stumbled upon a MathExchange question the other day which read

> Let $G $ be a simple connected graph with minimum degree 3. Prove that there exists a cycle in $G $ such that removing it does not disconnect the graph.

I thought of tackling it because I had had a subject in which I talked about graphs and I thought I could tackle it. I tried a couple of approaches but none revealed fruitful:

- Induction on the number of vertices with the base case being  $n = 4$, but could not find a way to prove the inductive step.
- Supposing there was no such cycle and then deriving a contradiction. Nonetheless, when I supposed there was no such cycle, I could not derive any property of the graph that enabled me to find a contradiction.

And at this point I thought of something else:

> To prove the statement it suffices to show that if $T $ is a spanning tree of $G$, then $G\setminus T $ has a cycle.

And then I got stuck on something else. I know that given the removable cycle, I can find a tree in $G$ with that property. But is the converse true? Do all spanning trees of $G $ have such property? I could not find a way to prove it nor a counter-example. Can someone guide me to (dis)proving it?

Also, any hints on the first problem?

Comment: By removing a cycle $C$ or a tree $T$ from $G$ I guess you mean that the ***edges*** of $C$ or $T$ are removed, the vertices remain?

Comment: Here's a counterexample for your second question. Let $T$ be a path with vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8$ and edges $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_4v_5,v_5v_6,v_6v_7,v_7v_8.$ Let $G$ be the $3$-regular graph obtained by adding to $T$ the edges $v_1v_3,v_1v_4,v_2v_7,v_5v_8,v_6v_8.$

Comment: @bof yes that is what I mean. Only edges are removes. Should I edit my question?

Comment: No, it's clear enough, I was just being silly.